# Windows 10 - Unable to access Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) via installation media

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios

Recently, my PC with a [Gigabyte motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/in/Motherboard/B365M-D3H-rev-10#kf) and a 1 month old WD Blue HDD, ran into the following issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9LBn.jpg

The problem is that **I'm not able to access the Windows 10 repair option via the USB or DVD drive.**

I've done the following:

1. Accessed the hard disk via Ubuntu Live CD and I can access the
   files. Also run the SMART check(without any errors).
2. Updated the BIOS
3. Tried booting with an old spare HDD and its booting fine.
4. Loaded the default config of BIOS

*Still, I'm not able to access the Windows repair option in my 1 month old HDD.*

- Is it a hardware problem with the motherboard or with the HDD?
- Is there any way to remove the Windows 10 boot-loader and re-install it than the usual route?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your BIOS was not in EFI BOOT mode initially ... try booting without EFI mode and see if that works.

Comment: @Overmind: It was in EFI mode. Tried disabling it, but in vain.Tried booting with an old spare HDD and its booting fine

Comment: @MithunJohnJacob Create a windows bootable usb > boot > repair > Command Prompt > Type BOOTREC /FIXMBR, and then press ENTER > Type BOOTREC /FIXBOOT, and then press ENTER.> Type BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD, and then press ENTER. ; check if it fixes the issue ; will suggest to run chkdsk on windows drive as well ; And a question - what triggered this issue?

Comment: @Madhubala: I'm already having a bootable USB, the issue is that I'm not able to access the "repair" menu. Don't know what triggered this. No hardware was changed nor any software.

Comment: @MithunJohnJacob try re-creating the windows USB ; this may happen if filesystem of USB is corrupted or win USB wasn't created in correct manner

Comment: @Madhubala: Tested the USB with a laptop, its booting fine and the repair option is accessible.

Comment: @MithunJohnJacob seems like you already tried every possible way so will suggest you to recreate the USB ; use Rufus - https://rufus.ie/ and make sure to select correct options and do complete format manually before creating

Comment: @MithunJohnJacob if you use linux then you can try booting from it and use 'Boot repair' application https://askubuntu.com/q/226061/1095264 to repair windows bootloader

Comment: @Madhubala Linux tools are not needed to fix Windows boot issues... your first comment is correct - First try `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`, as `BootRec /FixBoot` can only be used on UEFI motherboards with the EFI partition mounted via `DiskPart`, then `cd <EFI-drive-letter>:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot && BootRec /Fixboot`, however if that fails, [`BcdBoot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di) needs to be used _(similar to `BcdBoot C:\Windows /s C: /f UEFI`)_, finally execute `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`

Comment: @JW0914: The problem is that I'm not able to access the "command prompt" to type these commands.

Comment: @MithunJohnJacob Hard reset your PC 2x in a row as soon as you see UEFI hand off to the Windows bootloader, which should load WinRE. If it doesn't, boot a Windows install USB and once the setup GUI loads, press `SHIFT`+`F10` to open a terminal, then issue `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`, rebooting once it's finished, regardless if it finds a Windows install or not. If that doesn't work, follow my last comment for issuing `BcdBoot`

Comment: @JW0914: When I try to hard reset it for the 2nd time, the HDD becomes invisible from the BIOS itself. Is this a boot/system partition corruption. Any other way?

Comment: @MithunJohnJacob Sounds like either a bad SATA cable or HDD... check out the HDD's S.M.A.R.T data by booting an Ubuntu install ISO, choose Try Ubuntu > Open a terminal and and issue the following: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install smartmontools` > figure out which `/dev/sdX` is your HDD via `ls /dev | grep sd` > `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX` and check for physical damage entries below the S.M.A.R.T values > run a short and long S.M.A.R.T test via `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdX && sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdX` and via results via `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX`

Comment: @JW0914: Tried the SMART test via Ubuntu and it was showing errors now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the faulty one month old HDD. Waiting for the replacement.