# How to restore an entire Windows 10 installation using Linux disk images

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, dd

I had created disk images of my Windows 10 installation using the **dd** command via a Ubuntu Live CD.

The old hard disk size was of 2TB and I wanted to restore it to a fresh hard disk of the same size with the exact partition sizes.

I know to restore the image file via this command:

```
sudo dd if=.<name of disk image file> of=<output location>
```

My question is what is the *correct and quick process* to restore the full Windows 10 installation with the least troubles which includes:

1. Windows 10 partition - 199 GB
2. EFI partition - 100 MB
3. Reserved partition - 16 MB

(I'm having dumps of the above 3 partitions)

Screenshot of HDD partitions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O775h.png

Please guide me on how to avoid the long process of re-installing Windows 10 and the installed apps.

Comment: Did you create a dump of the partition table as well?

Comment: @EugenRieck: I'm having dumps of the above 3 partitions.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Can you please explain more? I backed up the 3 partitions which was visible via Live CD

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: It's clear that he didn't.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: He doesn't understand what you're asking. He doesn't know the difference between disk imaging and partition imaging, or anything about the disk structure.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: He is not to blame, as Disk Manager or others only show partitions.

Comment: @harrymc Not to blame, I agree. I'm not blaming anyone. I'm only disagreeing with *you* about whether or not the status was clear. I can see your answer is designed to work without the saved partition table, so it no longer matters. (I'm not upvoting the answer only because I'm not a Windows guy and I really cannot tell if the answer is good. It probably is. Keep up the good work.)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I started using Linux 20 years ago, but lost touch of it since Windows was always my workhorse. I tried backing up from a dying HDD and I had backed all the partitions except the Windows recovery partition(sda4). I've updated the original post with the screenshot of my old HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you took a backup of the partitions, rather than of the entire disk,
and using in addition `dd` instead of a product better adapted to Windows,
the procedure should be as follows:

- Run a live boot and create one partition over the whole disk, leaving some
  unallocated space of about one gigabyte
- `dd` back the Windows partition
- Use a Windows boot media to
  [Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

In the future, better use a Windows-oriented
[Drive Cloning Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm).

Comment: None of the Windows-oriented Drive Cloning Software was detecting the partitions. That's why I used Ubuntu Live CD.

Comment: That's not possible or Windows wouldn't be able to boot.

Comment: Windows was not booting. Original problem: https://superuser.com/q/1582383/939111

Comment: Still, many of the Windows-oriented products, such as AOMEI, have boot media. They are also more efficient, as they don't copy unused sectors. Most important, they can take a backup of *the entire disk* rather than partitions, which includes boot sectors and partition table.

Comment: Thanks. I had used Windows based apps in the past and it worked well. This hard disk crash was quite unexpected since it was a new HDD. Also, in your answer, you meant to create the partitions at this stage: https://tinyurl.com/y3kqh45t
Right?

Comment: Yes, but why do you have so many partitions? I thought this was a new disk. Also, it's rather small.

Comment: The disk/image is not mine, just an image found on the net!

Comment: Worked fine, but the 3rd step was not needed; Win 10 booted without any hiccups!